# Notation for expansion of multivariable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation

Let $ f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be some analytic function. I want to say something like, as $ x, y \rightarrow 0 $, the taylor expansion looks like:
$$
f(x,y) = a x^2 + b y^2 + \text{(monomials of degree larger than 3)} 
$$
What's the cleanest way to say this? I was thinking for example, as $ x,y \rightarrow 0 $
$$
f(x,y) = a x^2 + b y^2 + O\left( \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}^3 \right)
$$
meaning to say, terms that are bounded by some constant times $ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}^3 $ as $ x,y \rightarrow 0 $ but I am not sure if this standard notation.